# Keeping axes fixed in an Animate of a 3D graphic

Tags: list-manipulation, animation

I am using the following code to animate a 20 3D `ListPointPlots`:

```
Dat2={{0.`, 0.`, 0.`}, {0.`, 0.`, 0.`}, {0.`, 5.`*^-8, 1.`*^-7}, {0.`, 
   5.`*^-8, 1.`*^-7}}[{{0.309017`, 0.077252`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`,
    0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0, 
   0}, {0.00041012`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`,
    0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0}}, {{0.587785`, 
   0.262821`, 0.0193124`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`,
    0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0, 0}, {0.00108769`, 
   0.000102527`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 
   0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0}}];

Animate[ListPointPlot3D[{Transpose[{Dat2[[n]][[3]], 
        Dat2[[n]][[1]]}] /. {x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ} :> {x, y, 0}, 
        Transpose[{Dat2[[n]][[4]], Dat2[[n]][[2]]}] /. {x_?NumericQ, 
        y_?NumericQ} :> {x, 0, y}}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}]
        /. Point -> Line, {n, 0, 19, 1}, AnimationRunning -> False]
```

However, each `ListPointPlot3D` has a different x range and y range, such that the axes constantly move in the animated picture, making for a poor comparison of the behaviour.  Is there any way to fix the axes in the `Animate` function?

Comment: Can you please provide examples from `Dat2` so that we can reproduce your problem?

Comment: @Sosi, it's pretty big so have uploaded some example data here: http://pastebin.com/baRTknJM

Comment: You only need to give a small working example. I am going to edit your post to have a smaller version of your list. Please check if it is still representative

Comment: Note that *Mathematica* starts list indices with 1 and not 0. `Dat2[[0]]` returns the `Head` of `Dat2` instead of its first element.

Comment: Ok, that is **some strange** data structure... Did you intend to use lists as the head of your lists?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed there is. Just specify the `PlotRange`.

As an example:

```
Animate[ListPointPlot3D[{Transpose[{Dat2[[n]][[3]], 
       Dat2[[n]][[1]]}] /. {x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ} :> {x, y, 0}, 
    Transpose[{Dat2[[n]][[4]], Dat2[[n]][[2]]}] /. {x_?NumericQ, 
       y_?NumericQ} :> {x, 0, y}}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 10^-6}, {-1, 1}, {-5 10^-6, 5 10^-6}}] /. 
  Point -> Line, {n, 0, 19, 1}, AnimationRunning -> False]
```